# lost password link not working for my site

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password

I use Wocommerce to use the custom login page using the code `[woocommerce_my_account]` but when I click on forget password it not working for me. This link `https://app.mysite.com/?action=lostpassword` is created when hover on forget password but it redirects me to the same login page. `https://app.mysite.com`

Answer (score 1):

try to check your lost password url in woocommerce settings. There is a section with account endpoints. Check is this two urls adress are the same.